# SSE 4.1 vs SSE 4.2

Tags: c

I've been testing a SIMD C Program recently with the purpose of omparing O0 abd O2 optimisations.After quite a bit of long tests I noticed that I'm using -msse4.2 in one compilation and -msse4.1 in the other one. Is this a problem that requires that I do the measurements again? Or is the difference just extra instructions that ,if unused, do no present a problem?

expected no difference

Answer (score 3):

Run

```
gcc -O2 -g -msse4.1 file.c ... -c -o file1.o 
gcc -O2 -g -msse4.2 file.c ... -c -o file2.o 
objdump -d file1.o >file1.od
objdump -d file2.o >file2.od
diff -u file1.od file2.od >file.diff
```

, and then examine the difference of the assembly instructions (SSE 4.1 vs 4.2). If there is no difference, then the two versions behave identically. If there is a difference, the two versions may differ in speed, so you should write and run a benchmark to figure out which one is faster on a specific CPU.

---

In general it's impossible to answer your question (whether SSE 4.1 or 4.2 is faster) based on the info you have provided. Here are the factors which influence the final outcome:

- assembly instructions, affected by

  - C source file
  - C include files used
  - C compiler (e.g. `gcc`)
  - C compiler version
  - C compiler flags (e.g. `-msse4.1`, `-msse4.2`, `-O0`, `-O2`)
- CPU on which the program is executed
- operating system and other programs running at the same time

If the assembly instructions are identical, then the rest doesn't matter (considering SSE 4.1 vs 4.2). The `objdump` commands above retrieve the assembly instructions, and the `diff` command above displays the difference.